# Convert string to decimal ascii (dec) representation in AHK

Tags: loops, parsing, autohotkey

I've been struggling to get this to work for a little while and debugging it has been a pain... I'm running into a few different issues.

I prompt for user input something like this:

```
InputBox, stuff, Enter information, Enter obfuscated information in the box below,,,,,,,30000,
dexStuff= ""
Loop, Parse, stuff
    dexStuff:= AscToDec(%A_LoopField%)
```

The AscToDec function is painfully simple:

```
AscToDec(c){
    return Asc(c)
}
```

This is ending up with dexStuff as 0000 when I enter "test" as my string.  If I change the call of AscToDec() to just MsgBox %A_LoopField% it prints out t e s t in different popups.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to append to dexStuff, so that the result of `test` is `116101115116`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate the converted characters of your input, use this:

```
InputBox, stuff, Enter information, Enter obfuscated information in the box below,,,,,,,30000,

Loop, Parse, stuff
    dexStuff := dexStuff . Asc(A_LoopField)

MsgBox %dexStuff%
```

Comment: You both had the correct answer but you came in a little bit after.  Sorry I only have one upboat to give.

Answer (score 1):

I see two bugs in your code. First, initializing `dexStuff` isn't necessary, but if you do so, use either `dexStuff=` or `dexStuff:=""`, not `dexStuff=""` which sets `dexStuff` to two quotation marks.  Second, you don't need to dereference `A_LoopField` in your function call by using percent signs.

**Here is your corrected code**

```
InputBox, stuff, Enter information, Enter obfuscated information in the box below,,,,,,,30000,
dexStuff:=""                           ; := operator, not =
Loop, Parse, stuff
    dexStuff:= AscToDec(A_LoopField)   ; A_LoopField not %A_LoopField%
```